# How to find all the row combinations of two dataframes in R?

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I am trying to return the combinations of all the possible rows of the following data frame for `n` times.

```
test <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),3))
```

For example, now the `test` is a data frame of 3 columns and 8 rows as follows:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    0    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    0
4    1    1    0
5    0    0    1
6    1    0    1
7    0    1    1
8    1    1    1
```

For example, combinations with `n=2` would then provide a data frame of 6 columns and 64 rows. It is also acceptable if the result is in a list of 64 main elements where each element returns a combination of the two data frames.

I feel that I can still use `expand.grid()` but did not manage to use it correctly, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out as soon as I posted the question.

I can just use the code of the `test` as follows:

```
expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),3*n))
```